# How to create a DataSet with 29 columns in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a dataset from an RDD.
Here is my code :

```
val word = lines.map(_.value())
                        word.print()
                        word.foreachRDD( rdd => {
                            for(item <- rdd.collect().toArray) 
                            {
                                val s=item.split(",")
                                if(s.length ==37){
                            val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq((s(0),s(1),s(2),s(3),s(4),s(5),s(6),s(7),s(8),s(9),
                                s(10),s(11),s(12),s(29),s(30),s(31),s(32),s(33),s(34),s(35),s(36))));


                                val dataset = sc.parallelize(Seq((s(0),s(1),s(2),s(3),s(4),s(5),s(6),s(7),s(8),s(9),
                                s(10),s(11),s(12),s(13),s(14),s(15),s(16),s(17),s(18),s(19),s(20),s(21),s(22),s(23),s(24),
                                s(25),s(26),s(27),s(28)))
                                ).toDS()

                            }
                            }
```

When I compile the above it is throwing the below error :too many elements for tuple 29, allowed 22
Scala version 2.11.11
Spark version 2.2.0

Comment: Use `StructType` to define the schema , create `RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]`, ??? , PROFIT!

Comment: can you please share some code?

Comment: I would use nested structures (complex types)...

Comment: I see you have a CSV. What you're trying to do here is incorrect. You don't have to use `rdd.collect.toArray`. You can directly get a dataframe by `spark.read.csv(path)`

Comment: @philantrovert I am reading the data from kafka stream (which is in csv format) and not from a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create a `case class` (you can change the `data type` to your requirement)

```
case class dataset(col1: Int, col2: Int, col3: Int, col4: Int, col5: Int, col6: Int, col7: Int, col8: Int, col9: Int, col10: Int, col11: Int, col12: Int, col13: Int, col14: Int, col15: Int, col16: Int, col17: Int, col18: Int, col19: Int, col20: Int, col21: Int, col22: Int, col23: Int, col24: Int, col25: Int, col26: Int, col27: Int, col28: Int, col29: Int, col30: Int, col31: Int, col32: Int, col33: Int, col34: Int, col35: Int, col36: Int, col37: Int)
```

And use the `case class` in your code.

I am going to create temporary string for test purpose and `split` the string as you are doing in the code and finally use the `case class`.

```
val item = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37"
val s=item.split(",").map(_.toInt)
Seq(dataset(s(0),s(1),s(2),s(3),s(4),s(5),s(6),s(7),s(8),s(9),s(10),s(11),s(12),s(13),s(14),s(15),s(16),s(17),s(18),s(19),s(20),s(21),s(22),s(23),s(24),s(25),s(26),s(27),s(28),s(29),s(30),s(31),s(32),s(33),s(34),s(35),s(36))).toDS().show
```

this should give you `dataset` with 37 columns

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10|col11|col12|col13|col14|col15|col16|col17|col18|col19|col20|col21|col22|col23|col24|col25|col26|col27|col28|col29|col30|col31|col32|col33|col34|col35|col36|col37|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   1|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|   7|   8|   9|   10|   11|   12|   13|   14|   15|   16|   17|   18|   19|   20|   21|   22|   23|   24|   25|   26|   27|   28|   29|   30|   31|   32|   33|   34|   35|   36|   37|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

You can change the case class and implementation to suit your 29 columns

Comment: What version of Spark & Scala are you using? Must be recent https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets the docs say "Case classes in Scala 2.10 can support only up to 22 fields. To work around this limit, you can use custom classes that implement the Product interface"

Comment: In Scala 2.11 the case class limitation of 22 fields has been removed, allowing any number of field. The tuples, however, are still limited to 22 fields.