# Can we use normal class instead of case class to create DataSet in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As per Apache Spark documentation, to create DataSet we need to create case class in Scala. Instead of case class can we use use normal class because we can't create more than 32 fields in case class in Scala . In that case how can we create DataSet if we are concerned about Type-safe.

Comment: Might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258417/how-to-get-around-the-scala-case-class-limit-of-22-fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a DataSet with 29 columns in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341253/how-to-create-a-dataset-with-29-columns-in-spark)

Comment: That limit was removed in Scala 2.11, which recent versions of Spark support as well.